# Elasticsearch add script filter into URL in php

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch

I am having problem with Elasticsearch script filter and Curl post URI.

I am passing the values using URL as below

My URL with parameters

```
   $params = rawurlencode('firstName:John');
    $url= 'http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?q='.$params.'&pretty=true';
```

My Json code:

```
    $options='{
    "query": {
     "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "(min..max).contains(doc.admitted_date.date.year)",
          "params": {
            "min": 1999,
            "max": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "citycount": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "cityid",
        "precision_threshold": 100
      }
    }
  }
}';
```

Curl passing:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$options);
    ob_start();
    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

When i pass the above query, it show wrong result. because we are passing parameters with URL and JSON in both formats. So one time it will take the parameters from URL only. Is there any way to pass both parameters or is there any other way to pass this? Is there any way to pass Script in URL in Elasticsearch PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to pass everything in the query, including the match on the `firstName` field:

```
$options='{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "firstName:John"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "(min..max).contains(doc.admitted_date.date.year)",
          "params": {
            "min": 1999,
            "max": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "citycount": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "cityid",
        "precision_threshold": 100
      }
    }
  }
}';

$url= 'http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty=true';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);             <---- also add this
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options);
ob_start();
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```